# How do I distribute fonts with my python package using python -m build?

Tags: python, matplotlib, build, setuptools

### Problem statement

My package relies on matplotlib to use a specific font which may not be installed on the target device.
I'm trying to install ttf font files from the source distribution to the matplotlib `fonts/ttf` directory, *after* building the package.

With `setuptools` slowly removing parts of its CLI (`python setup.py sdist/bdist_wheel`) and the possibility to use `build` (`python -m build`), I decided to build my package with the latter.

### What I tried

I tried modifying the `setup.py` from the outdated https://stackoverflow.com/a/34304823/8797886.
My question differs from this post in that I would like to use `python -m build`.

`setup.py`

```py
import warnings
from functools import partial

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install

def _post_install():
    # Try to install custom fonts
    try:
        import os
        import shutil

        import matplotlib as mpl

        import mypkg

        # Find where matplotlib stores its True Type fonts
        mpl_data_dir = os.path.dirname(mpl.matplotlib_fname())
        mpl_ttf_dir = os.path.join(mpl_data_dir, "fonts", "ttf")

        # Copy the font files to matplotlib's True Type font directory
        # (I originally tried to move the font files instead of copy them,
        # but it did not seem to work, so I gave up.)
        cp_ttf_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(mypkg.__file__), "ttf")
        for file_name in os.listdir(cp_ttf_dir):
            if file_name[-4:] == ".ttf":
                old_path = os.path.join(cp_ttf_dir, file_name)
                new_path = os.path.join(mpl_ttf_dir, file_name)
                shutil.move(old_path, new_path)
                print("moving" + old_path + " -> " + new_path)

        # Try to delete matplotlib's fontList cache
        mpl_cache_dir = mpl.get_cachedir()
        mpl_cache_dir_ls = os.listdir(mpl_cache_dir)
        if "fontList.cache" in mpl_cache_dir_ls:
            fontList_path = os.path.join(mpl_cache_dir, "fontList.cache")
            os.remove(fontList_path)
            print("Deleted the matplotlib fontList.cache")
    except:
        warnings.warn(
            "An issue occured while installing the custom fonts for mypkg."
        )
        raise

# Set up the machinery to install custom fonts.  Subclass the setup tools install
# class in order to run custom commands during installation.
class MoveTTF(install):
    def run(self):
        """
        Performs the usual install process and then copies the True Type fonts
        that come with shithappens into matplotlib's True Type font directory,
        and deletes the matplotlib fontList.cache.
        """
        # Perform the usual install process
        install.run(self)
        self.execute(_post_install, (), "Moving Custom Font to matplotlib.")


setup_movettf = partial(
    setup,
    package_data={"": ["ttf/*.ttf"]},
    cmdclass={"install": MoveTTF},
)

setup_movettf()
```

I used a `partial` `setup`, because I expect `build` to fill in all the other stuff from `pyproject.toml`.

`pyproject.toml`

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0", "matplotlib"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "mypkg"
etc...

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
mypkg = ["ttf/*.ttf"]
```

### What I get

When I use `python -m build`, I get

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypkg'
```

When I use `python setup.py sdist` and `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, the wheel is successfully build.
When installing the wheel with `pip install dist/mypkg-[].whl`, the install is successful and the matplotlib ttf library is populated with the custom fonts.

### What I expect

I expect `python -m build` to work with importing `mypkg` post-install, like the setuptools cli does.

Comment: You can not do this with Python packaging tools. You need to go beyond that. Some platform specific packaging tools. Think `.deb`/`apt` on Debian/Ubuntu or full blown executable installers on Windows (or `.msi` if it still exists).

Comment: @sinoroc So why was it possible in [2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34304823/8797886), but not anymore?

Comment: Because since then, people have realized that it was a bad idea, possibly insecure. Nowadays, the rule is that _pip_ and co. can only install files in the `site-packages` directory and a couple of other clearly defined directories. -- To be honest if you and your users only use the `setup.py` script, without using pip, then it will likely still work, because you can put any code in `setup.py` without restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this with Python packaging tools. You need to go beyond that. Some platform specific packaging tools. Think `.deb`/`apt` on Debian/Ubuntu or full blown executable installers on Windows (or `.msi` if it still exists).

This is for operations at "*install*-time"...

... but you do not need to do this at "*install*-time", the code of your application or library can contain functions to do this installation of the fonts at run-time.

On the other hand, if you and your users only ever use the `setup.py` script, without using *pip* at all (or any other modern installer), then it will likely still work, because obviously you can put any code you want in `setup.py` without restriction.

There might be some more details in these:

- [Should there be a new standard for installing arbitrary data files?](https://discuss.python.org/t/should-there-be-a-new-standard-for-installing-arbitrary-data-files/7853)

Comment: Answer accepted. I ended up including the fonts in the package, importing them with [importlib.resources](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html), and using them with the [matplotlib fontmanager](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties).