# pyproject.toml run custom installation script

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I have to download some binary files from a location during the installation to have all necessary data files in place for my program. What is the correct place to do this in `pyproject.toml`, the `setup.py` approach was simple having the full programming power. Is this still possible with `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: Not possible. Question already asked before. For example here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75029388 -- Why not add these binary files as package data?

Comment: Not good, then the only alternative is to use the legacy setup.py approach which seems to be more flexible and powerful? Bundling the binaries is not the best option, although the files are only between 400 MB and 5 GB including them might be still an issue for a package or even pypa has some size limitations.

Comment: You have to remember that nowadays there is no guarantee that the `setup.py` will be executed at all, and if yes, when. Nowadays the "build" happens in "isolation" (in its own virtual environment), which typically results in a wheel artifact and this wheel is used for subsequent installations. -- So if I were in your position I would probably not rely on using the "legacy approach". If really it is not possible to put the binaries in the distribution packages then I would go for a step that happens at "run time", something like NLTK does (or used to do, I have not checked in the past years).

Comment: @sinoroc Thanks for the info. Then I would have to write also a first run checker. I'm wondering why the new approach is not supporting all the previous features. I have found an argument that running scripts in insecure, but this is a mood point, since later running the malicious package gives the same result.